Why does The Terminator have its CPU set to read-write in 1984?
In The Terminator, the T-800 arrives in 1984 and acquires a disguise from some punks.
During the altercation is told to "go away" with specific language.

Later on, at its HQ he tells the landlord to "go away" with the same language.

The POV shot shows this option at the bottom of the list, implying it was added later than other responses.

This makes sense, being able to learn and adapt to how a group of humans speak, will help them blend in.
However, in Terminator 2: Judgement Day, in the CPU switch deleted scene, the "Uncle Bob" T-800 states:

My CPU is a neural-net processor; a learning computer. But Skynet presets the switch to read-only when we're sent out alone.


The Terminator was sent to 1984 alone, why was its CPU apparently set to read-write?

Since that's a deleted scene, can it be considered canon? It contradicts the events of Terminator 2 as well ("I know now why you cry" etc)

@F1Krazy It actually doesn't, since they remove that lock in that deleted scene. In fact the deleted scene is what makes the Terminator's transformation into more human behaviour over the course of the movie make sense in the first place.

I've seen that movie literally hundreds of time, but zero knowledge of that scene! Is it on a specific DVD release? I'll search the web myself for it right now, but just curious...

@OldPadawan It seems to be a Director's Cut of kinds. But it does seem quite prevalent, these days it's usually the version that's shown on TV here, too. I can highly recommend it, though. In fact I consider it a great example of a Director's Cut that genuinely adds to and completes the original film and adds context to scenes that otherwise tend to sit a bit out of place. The above scene is a great example of that.

Not sure if this can be an answer but what if the Terminator scenario is that it is simply a child-like list because it is simply a 'fake being a human better' subroutine, as in it is not really learning, just using its experiences to complement its infiltration better. That is, it is not learning at all. It's just building up better responses based on interactions but it is not learning from it all. The flip switch in T2 allows it to actually learn, gauge and respond better, not just to infiltrate but to better its programming. The T1, in read-only mode would never 'better' itself.


That said, theatrical T2 needs to have the scene cut otherwise T:DF falls at the first hurdle. IIRC anyway


"This makes sense, being able to learn and adapt to how a group of humans speak, will help them blend in." Isn't this the answer to the question contained within the question itself?

@ToddWilcox Not quite. The rest of the question after that sentence cites how this ability is turned off, which is why I'm asking

@StuperUser The time travel mission is very different from any other mission so adaptability would be more important. I thought that’s what you were saying. I think a better question might be why did Reese (or future John or the resistance) set the T2 T-800 to read only? It was probably cut because it doesn’t make a lot of sense.

The chosen response to the hotel manager/super/landlord is low on the list, but it's merely an assumption that it was learned from the encounter with the humans.  If you don't make that assumption, then the entry was already programmed into the menu of responses, and the T-800 in 1984 was in read-only mode.  This is a simpler interpretation, and following Occam's Razor, it's more likely to have been what happened than the T-800 being sent to 1984 in read/write mode or a paradox  between the events of the two films.

In brief, the scene you're referring to from T2, where John sets the Terminator's CPU to read-write was cut from the theatrical release and is thus considered to be non-canon, although it did make it into the Director's Cut on the DVD release.



Even if it were the case, the reality is that T2 was written and conceived five years after The Terminator and thus the choices made in the original film would be considered to be, at best, retconned.
I guess you could argue that the Terminator is merely responding to its surroundings (like protective camouflage) rather than actually learning any foolish notions like loyalty, friendship or mercy.
